# Resizing browser window on load

Tags: javascript, browser

I've built a page that users will be directed to after connecting to a public Wi-Fi network, but the default Safari window size is very small (approximately 935px wide).

I'd like the window to resize for my page to 1024x768, which I've tried using `<body onload="window.resizeTo(1024,768)">`, but it had no effect. The Safari window is a stripped-down version with no address bar/nav buttons. Can I still control its size? Is there a better method?

Comment: Better method: reaponsive webdesign...

Comment: I don't think you can control the browser via the script which runs inside of the browser...

Comment: Whether `window.resizeTo` method works via web sites or not usually depends on user prefrences.

Comment: It may also depend on whether the script was initiated by a user (eg within a click handler), and not the result of something like a timeout (or the page loading)

Comment: Oh actually it is possible, but it is so limited that it most likely won't work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo

Comment: @Jonasw Of course it's responsive, but the design I was given doesn't fit/look as intended at such a small width.

Comment: Then its not responsive